# JSON values are null

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I'm sure this is something really simple...

I have the code below...

```
<script>

function postUser() {
    var user = $('span').serialize();
    $.post('userManagement/setUser', user);
}

</script>


<span>
  Username : <input type="text" name = "userName"><br />
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
  Password: <input type="text" name="password" /><br />
  <button onclick="postUser()">Submit</button>
</span>
```

Nothing gets posted (as in the POST is literally empty according to firebug).

How do I POST this form?  I want to use jQuery just so I can get better at it rather than just putting it into the HTML.  My controller is expecting a JSON object that's just my user entity with the fields above as well as an integer for "access".

I'm using SpringMVC for the controller.

Thanks,

Comment: Try `<form>` instead of `<span>`.

Comment: I don't know the serialize function, but have you tried the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var user = $('form').serialize();
```

Then:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Username : <input type="text" name = "userName"><br />
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
  Password: <input type="text" name="password" /><br />
  <button type="button" onclick="postUser()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

`serialize()` is used for serializing form elements not `span` tags, try this:

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

```
var user = $('span input').serialize(); // or $('form')
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, do I even need the serialize?  Can I just do var user = $('span input');

Comment: @david99world you are welcome, yes it should be used for serializing the values, note that all input tags should have a name attribute.

Comment: Excellent, I don't want my page to do anything else which was why I didn't use a form as it made my page change to my homepage as well as show my variables in a GET along the url, which was a bit odd, so I just used span and posted using jquery.

Comment: @david99world okay, but note that not using form tags makes your document invalid.

Comment: When you say invalid, do you mean in regards to XHTML conformity?

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are experiencing is due to your misunderstanding of the [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function and proper HTML structure.

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form
>   elements.

Try the following:

```
var user = $('span input').serialize();
```

This will locate all input elements within a span element and assign the data to the `user` variable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qSr7k/